# Android - Simulate Home click

Tags: android

I know calling finish() in activity will produce same result as if user clicked on Back button; is there a similar thing for Home button? (would like to automatically show Home screen after certain action).

EDIT: Also, I would appreciate same thing for Menu & Search buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can simply use an Intent for that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I read this as "There's an intent for that" and chuckled a bit :)

Comment: there is no "Intent.ACTION_HOME" - it does not exist. According to the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html it should be:

"ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_HOME -- Launch the home screen

Comment: Thank you @mishkin! I think Romain Guy's answer should be edited in order to include your amendment.

Answer (score 7):

HOME:

```
Intent showOptions = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
showOptions.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(showOptions);
```

MENU:

```
openOptionsMenu();
// this won't work from onCreate
// if anyone has idea how it would work
// please post it as response
```

Answer (score 5):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
```

Answer (score 0):

The nearest solution to simulate home click that I found was:

On home button click system log:

> I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000
>   cmp=com.belauncher/.ui.activities.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid
>   1000 on display 0

Simulating intent:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(i);
```