# Give user choice of setting default home page

Tags: android, homescreen

I'm looking for a way to present the user a choice of setting the home page programmatically.
What I want is for my app to ask the user to pick their choice every time it starts up. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a work around for this? 
Thank you

Comment: I've tried the solution from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537522/how-to-reset-default-launcher-home-screen-replacement). Then I open up the home activity in the onCreate using this Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
     i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
     i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is [bring up the home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2752749/115145). If the user has not already chosen a default home screen, and there is more than one home screen installed on the device, the chooser will let the user choose a default. The user is welcome to *not* choose a default as well, as it is their device, not yours.